# Eliminating time from parametric questions

Tags: systems-of-equations, conic-sections, rotations, parametric

Is there a general technique to eliminate a parameter from two parametric equations? E.g. given the following two parametric equations dictating the motion of a point how can I eliminate parameter $t$
(standing for time)?

\begin{align}
x_1(t)&=\sin(2\pi t)+2\cos(2\pi t)\\
x_2(t)&=\cos(2\pi t)+2\sin(2\pi t)
\end{align}

Intuitively, I think that these are the parametric equations of a rotated ellipsis. Using Matlab I get the following figure
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}
x_1=\sin (2 \pi  t)+2 \cos (2 \pi  t)\\
x_2=2 \sin (2 \pi  t)+\cos (2 \pi  t)\\
\end{cases}
$$
set $$\sin (2 \pi  t)=s;\;\cos(2 \pi  t)=c$$
we know that
$$\cos^2(2 \pi  t)+\sin^2(2 \pi  t)=1\to c^2+s^2=1$$

the system becomes
$$\begin{cases}
x_1=s+2 c\\
x_2=2s+c\\
\end{cases}
$$
whence
$$\begin{cases}
c=\frac{1}{3} (2 x_1-x_2)\\
s= \frac{1}{3} (2 x_2-x_1)\\
\end{cases}
$$
now remember that $$c^2+s^2=1$$
$$\left[\frac{1}{3} (2 x_1-x_2)\right]^2+\left[ \frac{1}{3} (2 x_2-x_1)\right]^2$$
After some simplification we get
$$5 x_1^2-8 x_1x_2+5 x_2^2=9$$

Answer (score 3):

There isn't really a general method, I think. You have to judge each case separately. Here it looks like identities such as $\sin^2(a) + \cos^2(a)= 1$ are going to be helpful in eliminating $t$ terms.